# Increasing jCarousel visible image not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jcarousel

I tried increasing the number of visible images to 5 but still the carousel shows only 3 images.
I have also increased the width in css for jcarousel-container-horizontal and jcarousel-container-horizontal classes but still it shows only 3 images by default.

Can anyone help me out to overwrite the default parameter to show 5 images on page load as well as on scrolling the carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe its the size attribute you have to set...
Like so...

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
   size: 5,
   visible: 5
});
```

I think you may have to set these too...

```
.jcarousel-skin-ie7 .jcarousel-container-horizontal{
width:750px;//whatever width you need} 

.jcarousel-skin-ie7 .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
width:740px;//whatever width you need }
```

It looks like you may have already tried all this though?  What browser you using?

Comment: hmmm, can you post some code maybe??  Just all the relevant pieces

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
<?php foreach($this->listitemId as $key=>$listitem){ ?>

   jQuery('#mycarousel_<?php echo $listitem->id;?>').jcarousel({   
       
        size: 5,
        scroll: 5,
        visible: 5, 
 vj:'<?php echo $listitem->id;?>', 
        itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback
    });
<?php } ?> 
});

Comment: Having that php embedded in the javascript like that may be causing the problem, its hard to say....But I know I've had issues in the past, where once I changed the php to a JSON object which I then just loop through with javascript, things magically worked.

Comment: Also what is the vj: doing?

Comment: I am sending the dynamic id as parameter inside the js and using that parameter I am fetching the images for each slider in ajax

Comment: I know that, but I don't see vj: in any of the jCarousel docs..what is it for, and what happens if you take it out??  But also, if I were you....I would just reconfigure your backend to spit out JSON data, instead of php, and then just loop through that in javascript.  Much cleaner

Comment: vj is a parameter created by myself and also i have initialised it in carousel.

Comment: and also i am using joomla cms where i need to fetch all the images using the queries and display it in page

Comment: thanks for your replies i got fixed it by specifying value to variable o directly in minified js